# How do I pass a function to a backbone subview

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

The user selection view is a shared subview of many different views. The problem is that when a user is clicked, a different event needs to happen for every parent view. For example:

- If Task View is parent, clicking a user search result will assign that user to the task
- If Project View is parent, clicking a user search result will make that user the owner of the project

Is there any way to pass a handler to a subview? The code below passes the handler, but it is immediately executed when the subview is initialized.

```
ProjectManager.Views.BoardTask = Backbone.View.extend({

    ...

    toggleSelectUser: function () {
        let self = this;
        let userSelectionView = new ProjectManager.Views.UserSelection({
            collection: self.collection,
            attributes: {
                onResultClick: self.updateUser
            }
         });

         $(".main-container").append(userSelectionView.render().$el);
         userSelectionView.position(self.$(".board-task-user-picture"));
    },

    updateUser: function (user) {
        // Update the assigned user of the board task
    },

    ...
});
```

Comment: I think we need to see your how you are implementing "onResultClick" within your subview. I think the default backbone way to handle the code you have is to attach an "onResultClick" attribute to your `el`, but in that case you'd want to pass a function name, not the function itself. Plus I don't think that's a valid attribute...

Answer (score 0):

Binding the function to the parent view and then passing it to the subview in the options seems to solve this issue.

```
let self = this;
let userSelectionView = new ProjectManager.Views.UserSelection({
    collection: self.collection,
    onResultClick: self.updateUser.bind(self)
});
```